# What is the expected `contentOffset` of UITableView when calling reloadData()?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios10

I have a `UITableView` that displays custom cells. By pressing a button, the user can change the content of my `UITableView`

Scenario:

1. Load an array with 1000 elements
2. Scroll table to bottom (gives me about 20,000 `contentOffset.y` after scrolling)
3. On button pressed, I replace my array with 300 elements
4. Call `reloadData` in main thread (gcd)

After the step 4, what should be the correct new immediate `contentOffset.y` of my `UITableView`? I expected it to be 0 and my table scroll to top but for some reason it's not and does not scroll back to top. Is this the normal behavior of `UITableView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's docs... https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata

> For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are
>   visible. It adjusts offsets if the table shrinks as a result of the
>   reload.

So, yes, it's normal to *not* scroll all the way to the top on reloadData.

If you *want* it to scroll to the top, either use `setContentOffset` or:

```
.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: false)
```

Comment: does UITableView behaves that ways since the beginning? all these time I thought calling `reloadData` will reset everything. thanks for the doc link btw.

Comment: Yep, always been like that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is normal behavior of UITableView. If you an want that table view should scrolled to top after reloading, you have to do that using below code.

```
let newOffset = CGPoint(x: currentOffset.x, y: 0)
tableView.setContentOffset(newOffset, animated: false)
```

Automatically, UITableView retain it's scroll offset while reloadData function called.